# How to export and import Graphs with additional data?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, export, bugs, version-9, version-8

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier, persisting through 13.2 or later**

---

I'm trying to export and then later import graphs with additional data added such as `VertexLabels` and `EdgeLabels`. When I export a graph, such as the following, and then import it, I find that some information has been lost.

```
g=Graph[{1->2,2->3,3->1},VertexLabels->"Name",VertexStyle->Purple,VertexShapeFunction->"Diamond"];
Export["graph.gml",g];
r=Import["graph.gml"]
```

This will maintain some of the options, e.g. `VertexShapeFunction` and `VertexStyle`, but will lose `VertexLabels`.

```
PropertyValue[r,VertexLabels]
```

The above returns `{}`,showing that the data was not retained.

I have tried .graphml and .gxl formats as well, with the same issues.

```
Import["graph.gml",{{VertexLabels}}]
```

The above returns the following error:

```
Import::noelem: The Import element "VertexLabels" is not present when importing as Graphlet. >>
```

What is the best way to export and then import graphs while retaining all additional data?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think it must be an oversight in the graph export code (it also happens when exporting to graph formats other than [Graphlet](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/Graphlet.html)). If you use explicit labels in Mathematica, it gets exported properly, just the implicit `VertexLabels -> "Name"` does not.

Note that since the export formats do not have an equivalent of `VertexLabels -> "Name"`, you'd expect the export/import cycle to yield explicit `VertexLabels`.

So, I guess you should submit a bug report to Wolfram Research.

In the meantime, the work around of using explicit labels should not be too onerous; e.g.,

```
Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1}, VertexLabels -> Table[i -> i, {i, 3}],
  VertexStyle -> Purple, VertexShapeFunction -> "Diamond"]
```

---

This can be automated in `Export` by using something like

```
ExportGraph[file_String, g_Graph, opts___] :=
 If[Flatten[{PropertyValue[g, VertexLabels]}] === {"Name"},
  Export[file, SetProperty[g,
         VertexLabels -> Table[i -> i, {i, VertexList[g]}]], opts],
  Export[file, g, opts]]
```

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to import the graph into some other application, but simply save it for later use, I've found that just saving the graph in .m format preserves everything just fine:

```
Export["graph.m", graph]
```

This is the only approach I've found that preserves property lists, labels, everything.

Comment: Nice, that works much better for storing large graphs than GML.